How to mark children as favorites in SwiftUI
I'm trying to mark children in a list as favorites. In addition I want to create a separate list just for favorites. The thing is that both children and parents need to have the Bool "isFaved" in the directory.
Here is my code for my list and also how I tried to handle user input.
struct Directory: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id = UUID()
    let name:String
    var isFaved :Bool
    var children:[Directory]?
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, children: [Directory]? = nil, isFaved: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
        self.isFaved = isFaved
    }
}

struct DirectoryData{ 
    static var items = [
        Directory(name:"Item 1", children:
                    [Directory(name: "Item 11", isFaved: false),
                     Directory(name:"Item 12", isFaved: false)], isFaved: false),
        Directory(name: "Item 2", children:
                   [Directory(name: "Item 21", children:
                   [Directory(name: "Item 211", isFaved: false),
                    Directory(name: "Item 212", isFaved: false)], isFaved: false),
                    Directory(name: "Item 22", children:
                   [Directory(name: "Item 221", isFaved: false),
                    Directory(name: "Item 222", isFaved: false)], isFaved: false), isFaved: false)], isFaved: false)]

My list looks like this, I want to have another list where the favorites are "stored". The user will choose favorites by clicking on a star or a heart.
import SwiftUI

struct Program: View {
    let items = DirectoryData.items
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Section(header:Text("Items")){
                    ForEach(items) {item in DisclosureGroup("\(item.name)"){
                        OutlineGroup(item.children ?? [Directory](), children:\.children){child in
                            NavigationLink(destination: PDFUIView()){
                                Text(child.name)
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Item")
            }
        }
    }
}


I have added this in two files
    import Foundation

final class Database{
    private let FAV_KEY = "fav_key"
    
    func save(items: Set<Int>){
        let array = Array(items)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: FAV_KEY)
    }
    func load()->Set<Int>{
        let array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: FAV_KEY) as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
        return Set(array)
    }
    
}


and also
    import Foundation

extension ContentView{
   final class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
       @Published var items = [Directory]()
       @Published var showingFavs = false
       @Published var savedItems: Set<Int> = [1,7]
        
        var filteredItems: Set<Int> = [Directory]{
            if showingFavs{
               return items.filter{savedItems.contains($0.id)}
            }
      }
   }
}

But it won't work, I am quite new to SwiftUi so it might be some beginner mistake but I can't get it right.

I recommend to store a dictionary with an unique – and persistent across launches – identifier as key and  isFaved  as value to be able to identify the item.

Any examples on how to do that? I have found on YouTube but they use id as an int and not as an UUID(). Can I somehow change UUID to id as an int? I have tried this but I only get errors... As I said, I'm quite now to swift
